# typescript ways to get class variables as json object

Tags: typescript

is there a an easier way or built in way to get only public variables only  without functions or private variables from class as an object other than creating a  function in the class to return the class variables as object

**is there a way to have something like this, to get the an object like `PokerObject`**

> const TableVariablesAsObject = TablesArray[1]

**Instead of calling**

> const TableVariablesAsObject = TablesArray[1].getAsObject()

```
interface PokerObject {
  smallBlind: number;
  bigBlind: number;
  size: number;
}
interface PokerTable {
  smallBlind: number;
  bigBlind: number;
  size: number;
  GetNextPlayer: (extra: number) => number;
  getAsObject: () => PokerObject;
}
class Poker_Table implements PokerTable {
  public smallBlind: number;
  public size: number;
  public bigBlind: number;
  private id: string;
  constructor(id: string, size: number, smallBlind: number, bigBlind: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.smallBlind = smallBlind;
    this.bigBlind = bigBlind;
    this.size = size;
  }
  getAsObject(): PokerObject {
    return {
      smallBlind: this.smallBlind,
      size: this.size,
      bigBlind: this.bigBlind,
    };
  }

  GetNextPlayer(extra: number): number {
    //retutrn sum number
    return 1;
  }
}
```

And putting classes in array

```
const Table1: PokerTable = new Poker_Table("1", 2, 1, 1);
const Table2: PokerTable = new Poker_Table("1", 2, 1, 1);
const Table3: PokerTable = new Poker_Table("1", 2, 1, 1);
const TablesArray: Array<PokerTable> = [Table1, Table2, Table3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make static method to set values instead of setting value in constructor

forexample here I set create method to create new PokerTable

```
  static create(id: string, size: number, smallBlind: number, bigBlind: number){
    const pokerTable = new Poker_Table()
    pokerTable.id = id;
    pokerTable.smallBlind = smallBlind;
    pokerTable.bigBlind = bigBlind;
    pokerTable.size = size;
    return pokerTable

  // or 

   return pokerTable.getAsObject()
  }
```

and when I return it it won't return private value (only publics and methods)

and for getting that as object (without any method) you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

like this :

```
const Table1 = {...Poker_Table.create("1", 2, 1, 1)};
```

here is [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=54&pln=43&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDW0DyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZAZwFs4AbRgIUdABMAuZEAVzp5oAbirI8wAOZtOPfoJFiawAF4Q5AoVFEBfCqEixEKDNigAVOHkYpK1ek1bsQ3XpsXUJ056-lbR9qrqbgraYgDiEGAAchAAHmCojHAAntA8ABTxYFBwGqEAlMgAvAB8If5iklEAgjT4RCSZRWVoWLiExGC6FAjJNDRtZgD6ltYowHQADjZ0EOCDptBjNuRiU3zWwAi0DMwyLgCE%20ZXUG1s7ymrHFR7I5%20w7XgccN353U1DAAG5wkMjAV48Gg5UCSUQUJRgP7bZAIKAQP4QDKA4GgkCSAA0tCCJ2g2Ic%20x8eKg2OexNuUAKdmocPQIBB93aFisq2KvAgAHchtBRqzkQUxGdmSsIAA6QElAEcAK0qYi-liwlOThS5UvWXCsyisXk1XsvUuTVM7WKq4odnm40IsB8KAgE3LfliPRVWr1TokDIFHhLKANLprWnIG12h004PqilgAAWwBoSr2KpcmKFtPNPFj8aVQVTwc8UhembjCcNHDztJ0std1EiMWySVS0CyCVyJJ9lKDtIA9N3QzkHTQBJS06H7cgAIzViiuhD0xmiidSshi1d%20vnjMXwxGQDIAIgne%20xACZsROzwUq5DevP0DYxYx0JIMouCkA)

Comment: the classes are heavily mutated after being added to the array ,that is why i am storing them in a array. what i asking if i can get a snapshot of the variable at a given time

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMTgXzgMyhEcDkMAzgLQwQQA2ARgKaUz4BQTwAdjLVJgIYDGtOAAUIAay4B5agCtafeAiZxlcIiB6VKAIUrsAJgC44bAK4g6UANxKV1YAHMd%20o6fNdrK1cABetF2YtrNFYOLl4BYTEuABUeakpBRU81DW1dNkNjAPcbZTtHdMzXQNyvX383K1KAcVoYADlaAA8YIUoeAE8uIwAKZpgoHgqLAEo4AF4APizKoKY%20dqIiSPEoAH1Y%20MFQMASQWg5lkVXNhMRSsBN44D5VdU0nDOGcz0vr26IfPxmS16vdW75R5FbJVV5QYAANx4nDgwEyRAG7HsHhUYAh0NhbAgbAAoq4uHEEgBJPQAQiMiIhbBRpT4OKpJnk0B68MpSJpABoyt9ilxuSkHoVnlBuUDhT8uGMkp4VDAABbAIgAOnhEzhelRsrgCqVysFaX06oNwK1st1KvFRvGcCtGTNngt%20q%20xq%20DpUUlk8mVelomHYtCEODAXBgHR6Fu5%20GxeIJgy2pPwnNK2uUCHpbH99hM8YSRgGJlo3IOZkJWyMvEoRCLcAA7hCYETvgWa9DKIWjPC0CNSsFPLUGv02p0uH0WoMRSMRedU3AAPRzqB1EwDNiqMySqAplRLmA5tcARjNfZUpXIACkAMoSeo9KcrSQyOQKbfKXf7uBgG6iACCmgjirLDwRxRFAnrPtyADa%20B2noSYEJ8vjwfgJqFPgAC6PaeMEwRMJgJhsPIwA4p%2035-pQAA80TcgA0nA-QHHoyw9OIHQQJgcDRCMkHoZMPSlBAMhGNRcCsUQRisexnH0S0jHLDRkF8lA6FwAA-HAdFGMgyr1BAxKZlwFGQcqJk0dyuJNAsJi%20hRkkcSJClKbxvFMPe0Qzjuy5QGu4HetguD4kitBECxtAdCq6hgCxEzTJBojcoJ0hxehmFjMBcA8GwHRMLhCTwGA6psLQtYPuspy0D0%20DAXB3IHgATAAzNyjUACzci1ACsABsPYZkQVC0MqlAQPYlVgAY8FgD2C5wPK6VqtQK7GBA8Axvipa5rQpLzAyA1DSNlUICZypgGgE3ckdJmndNc6zel2IakQO1sP1CT7aNhAQOe-VsOdn7Khe163iMN13csD3wkQ3JKhlqgcvYz2vYNw0fVSyLAJgHR-VeN76vDGPhlNIxAA)

```
import { F } from 'ts-toolbelt'

interface PokerObject {
    smallBlind: number;
    bigBlind: number;
    size: number;
}
interface PokerTable {
    smallBlind: number;
    bigBlind: number;
    size: number;
    GetNextPlayer: (extra: number) => number;
}
class Poker_Table implements PokerTable {
    public smallBlind: number;
    public size: number;
    public bigBlind: number;
    private id: string;
    private nonEnumerableId!: string;
    constructor(id: string, size: number, smallBlind: number, bigBlind: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.smallBlind = smallBlind;
        this.bigBlind = bigBlind;
        this.size = size;
        // make nonEnumerableId nonEnumerable
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'nonEnumerableId',
            {configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true, value: id})
    }
    GetNextPlayer(extra: number): number {
        //retutrn sum number
        return 1;
    }
    
    toJSON(): PokerObject {
        return pickAll(this as PokerObject, ['bigBlind', 'size', 'smallBlind'])
    }
}

function pickAll<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(
    obj: T, keys: keyof T extends K[number] ? K : F.NoInfer<[...K, Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>]>
): T {
    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, obj[k]])) as any
}

let p = new Poker_Table('asd', 123, 234, 456)
console.log('p:', p)
// has id but not nonEnumerableId
console.log('{...p}:', {...p})
// has no ids
console.log('toJson:', p.toJSON())
// has no ids, is a string
console.log('stringify:', JSON.stringify(p))
```